# How to create navigator series for Highstock stacked column chart

Tags: highcharts, stacked-chart

I have a stacked column chart. In this chart the navigator is blank and it doesnt show the proper line.
[image: Navigator Blank]

I want create the series for stacked column chart. What should be the structure of the series?

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle? See similar topic - demos placed over there can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740313/highstock-column-chart-data-grouping-causes-data-to-scroll-independently-of-ax

Comment: Just to clear - navigator shows only first series approximated. If you have multiple series, then navigator will show more space, but still only one "inside". See [this enhancement request](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2361925-allow-navigator-to-have-multiple-data-series).